# opening a url with hashes

Tags: ios, objective-c

this is my url which I want to open from the IOS App :

```
 NSString *urlString = @"https://cms.topmerits.com/CRM/feedback#/1715171559ae979371687#/10306";
```

when I encode it, the hashes are transferred to %

```
NSString *feedbackUrl = [urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

therefore the new url is :
https://cms.topmerits.com/CRM/feedback%23/1715171559ae979371687%23/10306

which does not open, it leads to a crash on the server side. any idea how to solve this issue

Comment: Are you using webView?

Comment: '#' is a reserved character. It is used to indicate an anchor in a URL. You might find your url works by removing the '#' characters.

Comment: no I'm using safari

Comment: I removed them, it didn't work